# Java. Не могу подключить apache poi

Tags: java

Использую версию 5.0.0

`pom.xml`

```
      ...
      <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
          <artifactId>poi-scratchpad</artifactId>
          <version>5.0.0</version>
      </dependency>
      ...
```

От этой библиотеки мне нужно 2 вещи

`org.apache.poi.hwpf` для парсинга .doc

`org.apache.poi.xwpf` для аналагичного парсинга .docx

Проблема заключается в том, что java не видит `org.apache.poi.xwpf`

```
 problems: 
[ERROR]         org.apache.poi.xwpf cannot be resolved to a type
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> org.apache.poi.hwpf для парсинга .doc

Данный пакет находится

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-scratchpad</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0</version>
 </dependency>
```

> org.apache.poi.xwpf для аналагичного парсинга .docx

Данный пакет находится

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
    <artifactId>poi-ooxml</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.0</version>
</dependency>
```